# Configuring environment variables prior to creation of dev container

Tags: visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

I am trying to integrate the [Remote - Containers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers) with my `docker-compose.yaml`.

However, my compose file is making use of the [variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#variable-substitution) feature.

```yaml
services:
    command: yarn server
    environment:
        MONGO_URI: mongodb://database:27017/todo
    ports:
        - ${SERVER_PORT}:3000
        - ${SERVER_DEBUG_PORT}:9320
```

Typically I set these variables from a `Makefile` that wraps the `docker-compose` commands I run to start my development environment.

#### How can I set these environment variables before the extension creates the **Dev Container** via `docker-compose`?

I've attempted to use the `initializeCommand` in the following ways.

`devcontainer.json`

```json
"initializeCommand": ". ./env.sh"
```

```json
"initializeCommand": "source env.sh"
```

I also attempted to use `remoteEnv` in the `devcontainer.json`.

I also attempted to set `settings.terminal.integrated.env.linux`.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? This is still an issue for me. I replied to a GitHub issue but I'm unsure the VSCode team is even aware this is a problem. You can technically use a `.env` file but in our codebase we actually commit the `.env` file and keep a separate `.env.secrets` file for secrets.

Comment: Cross posted a bug report on the appropriate GitHub repository.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/issues/1385

Comment: Can you use /etc/profile?

Comment: @Carson, that seemed promising, but adding "export MYVAR=something" to /etc/profile did not allow variable to added in my case.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't seem possible to pass env created in the initializeCommand as env variable to the docker build command. My solution is to create an env file in the initializeCommand and pass it with the build context.

Here is the .devcontainer/devcontainer.json

```json
{
  "build": {
    "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
    "args": {
      "USERNAME": "${localEnv:USER}"
    }
  },
  "initializeCommand": "echo -e \"USERNAME=$USER\nUSER_UID=$(id -u $USER)\nGROUPNAME=$(id -gn $USER)\nGROUP_GID=$(id -g $USER)\" > .devcontainer/.env"
}
```

And in the Dockerfile

```
FROM xxx

ARG USERNAME=user
USER root

# Copy the .env file to the container
COPY .env /tmp/.env
# Source to use it
RUN source /tmp/.env && rm /tmp/.env && \
    if getent passwd $USERNAME; then userdel -f $USERNAME; fi && \
    if getent group $GROUPNAME; then groupdel $GROUPNAME; fi && \
    if getent group $GROUP_GID; then TMP_NAME=$(getent group $GROUP_GID | cut -d: -f1); groupdel $TMP_NAME; fi; \
    groupadd --gid $GROUP_GID $GROUPNAME && \
    useradd --uid $USER_UID --gid $GROUP_GID -m $USERNAME && \
    echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME && \
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME && \
    chown $(eval echo ~$USERNAME) && \
    chmod 755 $(eval echo ~$USERNAME)

USER $USERNAME
```

Comment: I found need to  use '.' instead of 'source'.  This error when using source: 
`> [builder 7/7] RUN source /app/.env.secrets && rm /app/.env.secrets && ... /bin/sh: 1: source: not found`

Comment: hey @Tom, thank you for sharing! this could be a great trick to achieve what i need to do i.e. run the container with a custom uid and gid, available at launch time.
do you have any update on this? i mean, is this approach still valid, or you've found another solution? thanks in advance!

Comment: The provided code will likely not work because at the last line `$USERNAME` is not correct since ARG is not overwritten by commands in RUN. My solution was to have a static `USERNAME` with a `USER_ID` and `GROUP_GID` taken from the .env file generated by `initializeCommand`